# "Introduction générale" par rapport à "Introduction"

Tags: expressions

Je remarque en parcourant des mémoires de master que certains commencent par une "Introduction" et autres par une "Introduction générale": sachant que dans ce cas il n'y a pas des chapitres dont le titre serait  "Introduction" et qui justifierait ainsi le terme "général " pour une introduction qui chapauterait les autres.
Qu'est-ce qu'apporte le terme "général"? Avec ou sans n'est-ce pas la même chose; ≈

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Introduction générale* signifie que l'introduction apporte des informations préliminaires à toutes les parties. Ce n'est pas toujours le cas: souvent, une introduction apporte des les informations préliminaires qu'à la première partie, qui apporte les informations nécessaires à la seconde partie, et ainsi de suite: l'introduction n'est alors pas générale, car elle n'introduit pas d'autres parties que la première.

Le terme *général* peut aussi apporter l'indication que le l'introduction présente le sujet du mémoire dans un cadre *large*, ce qui peut s'opposer au reste du mémoire qui est plus focalisé sur un sujet *précis*.